# No provider for Http! Error: No provider for Http! at injectionError

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http! Error: No provider for Http! at injectionError

Component File:

```
import { Component,Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Camera } from 'ionic-native'
import firebase from 'firebase'

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-user-main',
  templateUrl: 'user-main.html',
})
export class UserMainPage {
    picdata:any
    picurl:any
    mypicref:any
  public people: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
    public alertCtrl: AlertController, public http: Http
     ) {
   // this.films = this.http.get('http://0.0.0.0:3000/');
  }   
}
```

**module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserMainPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicPageModule.forChild(UserMainPage),
    HttpModule
  ]})
export class UserMainPageModule {}
```

**Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http! Error: No provider for Http! at injectionError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:1788:90) at noProviderError**

UPDATE: Error Fixed after Adding Provider in App.module.ts

Comment: Try `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';` remove `Http` from import calss.

Answer (score 1):

This is not recommended at all. You must never inject an `HTTP` into your page's `constructor()`. It is an antipattern.You need to create a `provider` for that.After that, you can inject that provider into your `page`.

*CLI*

```
ionic generate provider MyProvider
```